# Angular JS: Change $location Params on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently using `$location` in my app so I can send parameters from the address bar to my `$http` GET request. Like so:

```
var params = $location.search();
$http.get(url, params).then(function(){
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to add an `ng-click` attribute onto an element in my view, so I can pass parameters into the address bar, so I can filter my GET request?

Something like so:

```
<div ng-click="genre=romance">Romance</div>
<div ng-click="genre=horror">Horror</div>

<div ng-click="year=2012">2012</div>
<div ng-click="year=2011">2011</div>
```

So when two buttons are clicked the queries chain themselves and url is transformed to: `app.com/movies?genre=horror&year=2012`, for example.

Is this possible with `$location` and am I going about this in the right way?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Search function is both getter and setter. You can e.g. put $location in $scope and then use it like this:

```
<div ng-click="$location.search('genre','romance')">Romance</div>
<div ng-click="$location.search('genre','horror')">Horror</div>
<div ng-click="$location.search('year','2012')">2012</div>
<div ng-click="$location.search('year','2011')">2011</div>
```

And modify $http.get:

```
$http.get($location.absUrl()).then(function(){...}
```